# How to cope with charset >128 && <256 in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, fileopendialog

In a WPF project I have a OpenFileDialog that gets a filename from filesystem and puts it in a textBox.

Now if I put the phi greek letter with charmpa in a filename
[image]

and create this

[image]

the textbox that receives the filename doesn't display the phi greek letter

[image]

and displays it with blank chars.

Comment: On a side note: This is *not* the greek letter phi (Φ)!

Comment: I don´t know what is your problem. I've tried to show that string (`ØØØØ.prg`) in a wpf textbox and it shows just right...

Comment: no repro. btw which font do you use in TextBox? Arial or some custom?

Comment: That was the problem thanx. I put Arial and that worked. I might want to put it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dialog on screenshot shows it uses `Arial` font. TextBox probably uses some other font which cannot display 216 char.